# How can I fetch the Url path with parameters for matching it to check access in Angular4+?

Tags: angular, parameters, router

URL: http://localhost:4200/#/users/company/5263/12

Component: UserDetailsComponent

I have added this route in my user-details-routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: "company/:companyId/:userId"
    component: UserDetailsComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminGuard]
}
```

Now I need this below value in my Guard file

> users/company/:companyId/:userId

admin.guard.ts

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        this.loaderService.show();
        let url: string = state.url;  
        // Here I need that value
        return true;        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my full routing url

> i.e. users/company/:companyId/:userId

by following line of code,

```
  const index = state.url.lastIndexOf(route.pathFromRoot[route.pathFromRoot.length - 1].routeConfig.path.split('/')[0]);
  url = state.url.substring(0, index) + route.pathFromRoot[route.pathFromRoot.length - 1].routeConfig.path;
  // url = users/company/:companyId/:userId
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can get query params like this using ActivatedRoute and then store it in one variable. Here is the example :

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
       let url =   this.activatedRoute.snapshot._routerState.url
       let urlSegment = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.path


  }

}
```

I have this url :::: http://localhost:4200/product/productDetails/79

My output of url is Like this ::: "/product/productDetails/79"

My output of urlSegment is Like this ::: "productDetails/:id"

Hope this will work.

Comment: I dont need to fetch the query params value. Actually here I need to get string value of the path of matched route 
i.e. users/company/:companyId/:userId

Comment: I edited my answer you can check. If that works let me know. I also provided output.

Comment: This thing I have tried already, but it requires string functions to be applied on url and urlsegment to get exactly what I require i.e. /product/productDetails/:id
Is there any other way?

Comment: And I need this value in canActivate function, there no ActivatedRoute injected. So this won't work in guard

Comment: I tried as you told in my project but it's not working. I inject ActivatedRoute in AuthGuard but when it hits breakpoint i got only last url like '/product'. May be as per my thought it's not getting actual url because it is hitting that AuthGuard before change of url so in activated route you will get old url.

Comment: Why you want that url segment in your AuthGuard Instead of component file ?

Comment: I need to make a HTTP call from there to validate my url